# What types of distributions (except the Gaussian) that follow for random jitter in a correlated signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, continuous-signals, gaussian, random

For the simple case, let's consider the correlated signal $s$ with jitter (without noise) as follows:
\begin{align}
s(t, \theta_i) = \cos(2\pi f (t + \epsilon_t) + \phi + \theta_i), ~~ i=0,1, ...
\end{align}
where the parameters $t$ is time, $\epsilon_t$ is a random variable for the random jitter in the signal $s$ with known $f$ and $\theta_i$ are frequency and $i$th-step angle which can be controlled. Need to obtain different models (e.g. histogram, PDF) for $\phi$ by assuming different distributions for the random variable $\epsilon_t$.

It is well-known the random variable follows the Gaussian distribution (with known mean & STD) and I need to know follows:

(1) what are the other distributions we can use for this modelling?

(2) what kind of distributions, we can use when the correlated signal has noise
as follows:
\begin{align}
s(t, \theta_i) = \cos(2\pi f (t + \epsilon_t) + \phi + \theta_i) + \epsilon_n, 
\end{align}
where the parameter $\epsilon_n$ is a random variable for the random noise.

Comment: Yes, all of the ones you mention occur in some specific phenomena. Why are you asking? "does XYZ exist"-questions are almost never really productive, because they tend to try to hide what you actually want to  ask. For example, what my best guess is that you're trying to build a system for a channel that you don't know and wonder whether you can safely assume Gaussian noise.

Comment: and before you ask "yeah, cool, can you then tell me where these occur?": then you'd be asking about four different things, without showing having done research at all (the wikipedia pages of these distributions actually do contain hints, for example).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I need to design a model for the random jitter + random noise in a correlation function of two signals. I know random noise follows the Gaussian distribution, but with the random jitter, will it follows the same distribution?

Comment: @Ganth Please edit your question to ask about jitter, and add more details about the scenario you need to model.

Comment: Hi @Ganth! Ah, jitter can have interesting distribution, and that usually depends on where it comes from. you described a lot more in your question than before, but you now have two random variables, $\epsilon$ and $\phi$, and you ask us about $\phi$, without giving us any info about it!